# Unable to send a big list over TCP Sockets - Blackberry

Tags: sockets, blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to send a list of 600 records over TCP/IP sockets using a java server and a Blackberry client. But every time it reaches the 63th record it stops, the odd thing about this is that if I only send 200 records they are sent ok.

I haven't been able to understand why it happens, only that 63 records equals aprox to 4kB, basically it sends:

- an integer with the total number of records to be sent
  And for every record
- an integer with the length of the string
- the string
- a string terminator "$$$"

Since i need to send the whole 600 i have tried to close the InputStreamReader and reopen it, also reset it but without any result.

Does anybody else have experienced this behaviour? thanks in advanced.

EDIT

Here the code that receives:

```
private String readfromserver() throws IOException {
    int len=_in.read(); // receives the string length

    if (len==0)     // if len=0 then the string was empty
        return "";
    else {
            char[] input = new char[len+1];

            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
                input[i] = (char)_in.read();

            StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
            s.append(input);

            return s.toString();
    }       
} 

private void startRec(String data) throws IOException
{
    boolean mustcontinue=true;
    int len=_in.read();     // read how many records is about to receive

    if (len==0) {
        scr.writelog("There is no data to receive");
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            if (mustcontinue) {
                mustcontinue=mustcontinue && showdata(readfromserver()); 
                    }
                else {                  
                    scr.writelog("Inconsistency error #19");                    
                }           
    }        
}
```

the function showdata only shows the received string in a LabelField.

The code in the server:

```
try {
  _out.write(smultiple.size()); // send the number of records 
  _out.flush();

  for (int x=0; x<smultiple.size(); x++)
  {
    int l=smultiple.elementAt(x).length();
    _out.write(l);  // send string length
      if (l>0)
        _out.write(smultiple.elementAt(x));         // send string

  }
    _out.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
  principal.dblog(e.toString());
}
```

smultiple is a vector containing the strings and everyone already have the terminator $$$.

Thanks.

Comment: This probably isn't directly related to your problem, but you don't need to send *both* the length of the string *and* a string terminator. What if the string you're sending contains "$$$"?

Comment: Can you include the relevant blackberry code in your question?

Comment: Since i send the length of the string i use the terminator only to verify if the string i'm receiving is fine, that why i use it :)

Comment: Are you running the receive code in its own thread? If you run blocking operations (reads from a socket) on the event thread bad things happen.

Comment: @Richard yes, it has its own thread, it's called SyncThread. I found a "more or less solution" by closing the connection every 200 records and restart from the last record received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 200 goes fine and 600 -not, because the latter number is bigger than **255** :-) Your code

```
int len=_in.read();
```

probably reads a byte and not an integer (4 bytes)